# nuxt.js -> Howto configure production/development settings

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a nuxt.js project with feathers. The client and server are to different entities, you start them seperatly. The client uses nuxt.js. I want to configure production and development settings.

Currently my nuxt.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    head: {
        title: "SITE TITLE"
    },
    env: {
        backendUrl: 'http://localhost:3001'
    }
};
```

What I would like is that if I start the client with 'npm run dev' development setting are used. I would like to have e.g. a different header and different backendUrl.

**Question**

What do I need to do to implement this?

Comment: If you want to use as production , you need to run `npm run build` and `npm run start`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my project

I put this code in nuxt.config.js

```
const config = {
    test: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'devdevdevelopment' : 'proproproduction',
    apiserver: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'developement apiserver' : 'production vbvbvbvbv apiserver',
}
module.exports = {
    env: {
        dev:config.test,
        server:config.apiserver
    },
}
```

and do so , You can set environment variables dynamically depends on devevelopment or production mode.

This code work for me. 
If you have anything better than this solution please let me know. :)

Comment: If you want to do External Configuration check this link I'm ok with it .
https://github.com/awronski/nuxtjs-examples/tree/master/external-configuration

Comment: And what happens if you have more than just development and production environments?

Comment: @Chris You make the chain deeper, e.g.: `test: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'something' : process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'dev1' ? 'something1' : 'something2',`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that [HninYuKo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9024168/hninyuko) has suggested but take it a step further. Install https://github.com/nuxt-community/dotenv-module and add a .env file, so that it becomes accessible to you anywhere in your Nuxt.js codebase. You now have environment-specific files that you can customize on dev or production, in addition to being able to invoke environment-specific builds from the command line.