# Conditional attribute in nuxt.config.js

Tags: vue.js, configuration, nuxt.js

I am developing a **website using nuxt.js**, and would like to have a configuration option in **nuxt.config.js** conditionally: I would like to change the router base when I run **npm run generate** (building static)

Here is the full config file for development environment (**npm run dev**):

```
const pkg = require('./package')

module.exports = {
  mode: 'universal',

  // if I uncomment the following three lines, the config is OK for npm run generate.
  // router: {
  //   base: '/app/'
  // },

  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: pkg.name,
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,500,600&amp;subset=latin-ext' }
    ]
  },

  /*
  ** Customize the progress-bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#fff' },

  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '@/assets/css/main.scss',
  ],

  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  */
  plugins: [
  ],

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    // Doc: https://github.com/vanhoofmaarten/nuxt-mq
    [
      'nuxt-mq',
      {
        // Default breakpoint for SSR
        // Breakpoints are bootstrap-vue Breakpoints
        // Doc: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/layout
        defaultBreakpoint: 'default',
        breakpoints: {
          xs: 576, // 576 not included
          sm: 768, // 768 not included
          md: 992, // 992 not included
          lg: 1200, // 1200 not included
          xl: Infinity
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  bootstrapVue: {
    bootstrapCSS: false, // or `css`
    bootstrapVueCSS: false // or `bvCSS`
  },
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  */
  axios: {
    // See https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module#options
  },

  serverMiddleware: [
    '~/api/contact'
  ],

  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    /*
    ** You can extend webpack config here
    */
    extend(config, ctx) {
      // Run ESLint on save
      if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The config works fine for both settings (so it compiles, the app is running correctly), but I would like to make it automatic, as I often forget to uncomment the **router** settings when I want to see the static version.

I haven't looked in the problem much, just read some SO questions and Googled a bit (for things like this: [nuxt.js -> Howto configure production/development settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017928/nuxt-js-howto-configure-production-development-settings) or this: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2940).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use an environment variable and include a condition on this environment variable in your config file:

```
const pkg = require('./package')

let config = {
  mode: 'universal',
  head: {},
  ...
}

if (process.env.NODE_GENERATION_TYPE === 'static') {
  config.router = {
    base: '/app/'
  }
}

module.exports = config
```

You would then need to use the following command line to generate your static website:

```
NODE_GENERATION_TYPE=static npm run generate
```

And you could also set up a script into `package.json` to make it prettier:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "generate:static": "NODE_GENERATION_TYPE=static dev",
    "dev": "..."
  },
  ...
}
```

You would then be able to run it using `npm run generate:static`

Comment: Thanks, your answer works :) I really hoped that it's kinda' easy for one who's more familiar with the topic than I am. The only modification I made was that I put **"generate:static": "NODE_GENERATION_TYPE=static nuxt generate"** in package.json, but that doesn't really change anything

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using ES6 object spreading:

```
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,
 ...process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && { router: { base: '/app/'} },
```

I also ran into a case where a module needed to be imported only in a production environment:

```
// Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' ? 'my-module' : function() {}),
    // In case it accepts arguments
    (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' ? ['@jabardigitalservice/nuxt-module-keycloak', {
       namespace: 'namespace',
       clientId: 'client',
       realm: 'realm',
       keycloakUrl: 'keycloak',
       redirectUri: 'redirectUri'
     }] : [function() {}])
...
```